# Azure function + queue + Api

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, queue, serverless

We have an problem while designing new API. The problem is that we have an MVC project and we want to connect it with new API. Our idea is simple (showed on graph): [Graph here!](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=APIExample#R7Vldb5swFP01SNvDJsB8Pqbpx%2FZQrVOidXskcAFrBEfGLGl%2F%2FQyYBGPStZmrdVXzEnyMjX2Or%2B8xGGi%2B3l3RaJNfkwQKwzaTnYHODdu2HNvjfw1y1yFe4HRARnEibjoAC3wPAjQFWuMEKulGRkjB8EYGY1KWEDMJiyglW%2Fm2lBTyUzdRBgqwiKNCRW9xwvIODWz%2FgH8CnOX9ky0v7GpWUfwzo6QuxfMMG6Xtr6teR31fYqJVHiVkO4DQhYHmlBDWXa13cygabnvaunaXR2r346ZQssc0sLsGv6KiFlO%2F%2FjbnwGyzEQNkdz0p2xwzWGyiuClvufAGOsvZuuAli19G1aaTIsU74N2fpbgo5qQgtG2OkgiCNOZ4xSj5CYMaLw5glfIaMRigDHZHJ2TtaeLLD8gaGL3jt%2FQNTMGsWHmhKG4PMlo9%2BflQwh6MxNLJ9l0f6OMXgsFpNpHC5uzms3YeXQgSZ4rHwF4hz9PDoxvIPO5Dc0BkMMFjoIFGR6FR4bANsYadc5PP9w%2BMaqAjlNlA3iOXlaeBDvfPdECZzJptj5dKUoI8fT5Feve9oeoj70uUfwjqYIfZsI4Xf0i0QaJslSPS%2BEhITWOQxGMRzYANIJXaAXfuBHU9RqGIGP4lD2KKT%2FGEG4L58I5uCI47kqQbvGg13CrHHbmjjsxRR92UlY5aeffTfpTinj7FHxD8Te%2BXorevT2%2F%2FAcH9N8VfiuKBovjsvqbAoa81cGgsP89cTNacQoXvo1V7QyPzphlVO073zHDPGyNRM1J11rr1FQXOSn5dQNp01aRDzB3vTMCMNFmz4kkUl9myKZx%2FcHR5MlfOnkjNnuHE%2BtBhycKjRF%2FWZcwwKd%2B1jC8pzjKg7xXmn%2BQ0RlYtTcGLJy1v4ocr09RDL%2FJHy9aZMCfOM5kTy1IIvrpYGmjGsStgs5rlhPKF2jC95ByUl5SsW1fsFc0yXFF%2BlbGWiccgrykukCMLZ6FQEW7vu4fCOTqEU49%2BDyWduIiqCsejvNOnlkFeGZrM78P8NKg8Le8gNe%2FY%2FzLvjM4ETnhi2hnHrz3OX%2FrSjqWeUE8XXT0xPHjSOE10%2B4WZDV2iW86RTfsZRFfP0zdfFmKPXnC5r6GqogyWpM2Et5jl7U79uaxw8sqsyEg%2B23PVHdd%2FJitiPc3mTwffPsLkbdUdBKYl7can77cTPj98QaHn%2BppCzx2LqzH0VPvJTZGIt8YJvUK3b4%2Fc%2Fv44NrSjU8tER4z1IaUnxuS3J8PkZ300TV%2BKs9DryzdAMR840L9KfKEafegt%2Bp4UfRPv448kvqnX9P91ELoBklhG%2FQe4YRB6eoKQFw8frDqZDl8F0cVv)

The problem is that we don't want 'ask' API for new authorization token (jwt authorization) every single time when we put message to queue. We invented that we can check if token not expired when we tried to put message to queue (ExpiredProperty in MVCApp memory). Anyway the situation may occur that token is valid to for e.g. 2018-01-01 00:00:10 and when we try to put message the date is: 2018-01-01 00:00:09.321 so for our program is still valid.

On API side we just take message from function decode this and check if token is valid (have api secret key, not expired) then if its ok we will put this message into AzureTable, but if it's not we don't know what we can do with this message.

We can't 'forget' this invalid message and also we can't let this message to be putted into db.

Have you got any idea how we can handle this?
Thanks for all responses.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you not have a refresh token?

Comment: If you try to POST to your API and the Token is invalid, I assume you receive an Exception or at least an Error Code which you can then throw an Exception with.

If the messages aren't critical to be processed chronologically, then I would go for the approach to read the failed messages from the poison queue (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/poison-message-handling) and performing a new Authentification.